# Inverse Laplace transform of the Meijer G-function

Tags: integration, special-functions, inverse, laplace-transform

$$\mathcal M_Y(s)=\frac{1/\sqrt\pi}{\prod_{i=1}^N\Gamma(m_i)}G_{2,N}^{N,2}\left[\frac4{s^2}\prod_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{m_i}{\Omega_i}\right)\Bigg|_{m_1,m_2,\dots,m_N}^{1/2,1}\right]\tag{3}$$
$$f_Y(y)=\frac2{y\prod_{i=1}^N\Gamma(m_i)}G_{0,N}^{N,0}\left[y^2\prod_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{m_i}{\Omega_i}\right)\Bigg|_{m_1,m_2,\dots,m_N}\right]\tag{4}$$
([Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmVrB.png), [Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTDDq.png))

Can any one tell me how they got equation (4) out of (3)? Attached is the equations. They say that they did the inverse laplace trasnform to get it, but i don'y know how! if any one used Mathematica to solve it, that would be more than enough. where equation(3) is the moment generating function and equation (4) is the pdf.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel: you have removed equation 3 and put (4) again instead of it !! and now i can't edit it. will you please return it back?

Comment: Have added back equations.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: okay, thanks

Comment: The proof is in this reference:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904159/inverse-laplace-transform-of-the-meijer-g-function